# facebook repeatedly prompts for permissions

Tags: ios, facebook

every time you tap the facebook login button you are asked to accept the read permissions regardless of whether you just accepted them on your previous login attempt. you can accept the read permissions and land back in the app, only to logout, login, and be presented with the read permissions to accept yet again.

this issue did not exist prior to 3.5, 3.5.1, or the new 3.5.2. Due to this issue my application is stuck on the latest version of the pre v3.5 version of the sdk (3.2.1).

to me, this sounds like a bug in the facebook sdk/app but when i submitted this bug report it was marked as "triaged/low priority" and had the following note attached: "Thanks for the report. We are prioritizing other reports at the moment. You may want to check out http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/" so here i am.

my logic behind the assertion of it being a facebook server side thing is that we are making an auth request to facebook. it is within the facebook realm that they decide what permissions you have and have not accepted. how can it be a fault on my side? it is not the developer's job to tell facebook what their own user has accepted or not.

heres the code that i have behind the "Login with Facebook" button touch up event:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

if (appDelegate.session.state != FBSessionStateCreated) {
    appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:permissions];
}

[appDelegate.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
    if([appDelegate.session isOpen]) {
        //login ui flow finished here
    }
}];
```

anybody have any thoughts?

Comment: you ask everytime to open the session?

Comment: not sure what you mean there. can you clarify a bit?

Comment: I mean : every time that you click on you button you execute that code?

Comment: yep. but if you have an already active/logged in session then you don't land on this page and don't see the button